# Why is my beamer presentation failing to compile when I include letters in my math?

Tags: beamer

Forgive me I am new to LaTex.  I have a presentation that I would like to do in Beamer, but it fails to compile when I include letters in my math statements.

For example, the following will compile,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Midterm Presentation of Doom}

\frame{\frametitle{Example}

$ 1 + 1 $

$ \lambda $

}

\end{document}
```

However, the following will NOT complile,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Midterm Presentation of Doom}

\frame{\frametitle{Example}

$ 1 + 1 = a $

$ \lambda * b $

}

\end{document}
```

The error that I get are

```
  Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available(Font) size <5> substituted
```

I am using TeXstudio 2.6.6 + MikTex 2.9, if this matters.

Comment: That is not an error, it's just an informational message

Comment: Prefer the syntax `\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}<BODY>\end{frame}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both your example codes compile with no errors, and both of them produce the warning messages

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available size <5>
substituted on input line 15.

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences up to 1.0pt have occurred.
```

As David has pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171016/why-is-my-beamer-presentation-failing-to-compile-when-i-include-letters-in-my-ma/171019#comment394040_171016), those are not errors but just warning messages informing you that some font sizes (`4pt`, in this case) were not available in the current font used, so LaTeX used a different back-up size (`5pt`) instead.

The warnings come from the fact that `beamer` defines (the definitions are in `beamerbasefont.sty`) and uses some non-standard font sizes `\Tiny` and `\TINY`:

```
\newcommand\Tiny{\@setfontsize\Tiny{4}{5}}
\newcommand\TINY{\@setfontsize\Tiny{3}{4}}
```

which are not available in the default CM fonts. You can prevent the warning in a number of ways:

1. By loading the `fix-cm` package if you want to stick to CM fonts.
2. By loading another font with arbitrary scalable sizes, such as `lmodern` (and using the `professionalfonts` font theme for `beamer`):

   ```
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
   ```
3. If none of the above is a valid option, as a last resource you can `\let` the problematic size to a familiar one, by adding to the preamble

   ```
   \let\Tiny\tiny
   ```

By the way, there's no need to explicitly load `amsmath` with `beamer`, since the class internally loads it.

Comment: Thank your for your help.  Using either \usepackage{lmodern} or \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} allows my presentation to compile with out error or warnings.